# Wavefunction of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

A self adjoint operator in general can be written as

$$\mathscr{L(x)}=\frac{d}{dx}\big[ p_0(x)\frac{d}{dx}\big]+p_2(x)$$

The probability current associated can be found in the standard way

$$\Psi^*\mathscr{L}\Psi-\Psi\mathscr{L}\Psi^*=\frac{d}{dx}\Big[p_0(x)(\Psi^*\frac{d}{dx}\Psi-\Psi \frac{d}{dx}\Psi^{*})\Big]$$

Since $\mathscr{L}$ is Hermition, the probability current must be conserved

$$J(x)\equiv p_0(x)(\Psi^*\frac{d}{dx}\Psi-\Psi \frac{d}{dx}\Psi^{*})=Constant$$

Now if we write the wavefunction as $\Psi(x)=R(x)e^{iS(x)}$ one finds

$$p_0(x)R^2S'=Constant$$

If $p_0(x)$ is taken as a complex function, how one reconciles that with the fact that $R(x)$ and $S(x)$ must be real? Is any one my assumptions here wrong?

Comment: $p_0$ must be real otherwise $\cal L$ is not Hermitian.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Moretti. The fact that not every self-adjoint operator is Hermition escaped my attention. As you pointed out, if $p_0$ is not real $\mathscr{L}$ is not Hermition and the probability current is not conserved.

Comment: This fact is not a fact. The fact is: every self adjoint operator is hermitian.

Comment: Sorry, I might have used the terminology loosely. Actually, I referenced George Arfken

"If a second-order differential operator L... satisfy the self-adjoint condition, Eq. (8.9)[$\mathscr{L}=\frac{d}{dx}\big[p_0(x)\frac{d}{dx}\big]+p_2(x)$], then it is Hermitian, given (a) a scalar product of uniform weight and (b) boundary conditions that remove the endpoint terms of Eq. (8.12)"

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see the point. However what  the book calls  self-adjoint condition should be called **formal** self-adjoint condition (which does not assure Hermiticity unless suitably boundary conditions are assumed). The use of a confused terminology does not help here...

Comment: Arfken is assuming that $p_0(x)$ is real. If it is not real then $\mathcal L$ is neither hermitian nor self-adjoint.